# How to change left icon in UITableView editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've seen many posts about how to change the "Delete" texts that appears on the right when editing an UITableView.

But what I need to do is to change the image that appears on the left when a UITableViewCell is editable.

I've tried with editingAccessoryView property, but it appears on the right as the normal accesoryView.

Is it possible to change the left delete (-) icon?

Comment: Have you thought of just using a custom table view cell and putting your own unique image where the delete icon would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the (-) icon, however, you can implement your own editing style.
Check UITableView's `setEditing:animated:` method where you can make your editing style on the cell

Answer (score 0):

Directly we can not change it but if you want then you can customize it. See the below link which help you:

Customized Demo Code: https://github.com/teameh/TableViewCustomEditControls

To change the color theme only: http://www.cumulations.com/blogs/11/How-to-customize-UITableViews-editing-mode